# Ionic 2 - set timeout to pop page to root after X seconds

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2

Currently when a user submits a form it shows and thank you overlay - after 2.5 seconds I want the overlay to disappear.

My currently code looks like this.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

import { NavController, ViewController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage';

@Component({
    selector: 'finish-page',
    templateUrl: 'finish.html'
})

export class FinishPage {

    constructor(
        public navCtrl: NavController,
        public viewCtrl: ViewController
    )
    {}

    ionViewWillEnter()
    {
        setTimeout(() => {
            this.navCtrl.popToRoot();
        }, 2500);
    }
}
```

But the page just stays on forever and never pops back to the root page

**EDIT:** I think I have the timeout working but now I get this error:

> Cannot read property 'popToRoot' of undefined

Comment: Show the complete code of the component. this.navCtrl has not been defined in the constructor, probably.

Comment: My bad will add - @ChristianBenseler added :)

Comment: Which Ionic 2 version are you using? There is no ionViewOnEnter method on ionic's page lifecycle. You can check them herehttp://ionicframework.com/docs/api/navigation/NavController/ I don't know if this is the problem.

Comment: Yea I was just trying different functions to see if any would work xD I changed it back to ionViewWillEnter()

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As Christian Benseler stated, there is not an ionViewOnEnter(); function closest thing would be ionViewWillEnter() or ionViewDidEnter();

Try to change those or even just use ngOnInit(); if those don't work, you may need to import your page and use **setRoot()** to accomplish your goal as seen below.

Don't forget to import your page that you're setting the root for though

```
ngOnInit(){
    setTimeout(() => {
        // this.navCtrl.popToRoot();
        // might try this instead
        this.navCtrl.setRoot(page);
    }, 2500);
}
```